# PDO to find where array values match multiple column values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to run a query to find whether a given search term matches any value for the three columns in the db. The first column returns a correct result set (i.e. the airport icao code column) but the other two don't return anything.

```
$inQuery = join(",",array_fill(0,count($search_terms),"?"));

$stmt = $wacdbpdo->prepare("
                        SELECT
                        *
                        FROM airportdetails
                        WHERE airport_icao_code IN ($inQuery)
                        OR airport_iata_code IN ($inQuery)
                        OR airport_faa_code IN ($inQuery)
                        " );
$stmt->execute($search_terms);
```

I do get this error however. Is the query trying to read by adding onto the $inQuery string values instead of going back to the start of the string for each column? How can I deal with this? Is there a better way to write this query? I'm new to PDO, and I'm thinking I'm probably writing this query in completely the wrong way?? Any help appreciated..

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: 
>       number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in ...

Comment: I would think that this error is pretty self-explanatory

Comment: You'll have to create an array with 3 copies of the search_terms.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton suppose to be like that

Comment: @chris85 That did it! Thanks a lot, I appreciate the help. I can see what I was doing wrong now too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a term for every placeholder. Since you have three groups of placeholders you should bind the terms three times.

```
$stmt->execute(array_merge($search_terms, $search_terms, $search_terms));
```